# Can I push/load a json file from Project_A to BigQuery of Project_B ? i.e. across the Projects

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions

Can I push/load a json file from Project_A to BigQuery of Project_B ?  If yes how ?
Code I tried

```
 os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = key_file_of_proj_B
client = bigquery.Client() 
client.load_table_from_file(
        source_json_file,table_ref_of_proj_B,location="US",
        job_config=job_config)
```

Now as I run this in project_A , CloudFunction starts throwing error as it cant find table_ref_of_proj_B ( coz its searching in Proj A) .

Also I tried playing around with Service_Credentials, for e.g. setting service credentials of Proj_B using  os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = proj_B_key_file in Proj_A but somehow it doesn't help.
Any thoughts ?

Use case: I have services which does some work for e.g. pulling data from a bunch of platform and just populating the data back to the BigQuery tables of the client as per their need.

Comment: What is the real purpose of your flow? I ask it because you may be trying something inefficient and I want to be sure to provide you with the right insights.

Comment: As a quick answer you don't need to put a dedicated keyfile from project B as the function's identity. Instead declare the associated service account to your cloud function in the IAM permissions of project B and set the right permissions on it. {bigquery.tables.create, bigquery.tables.updateData,bigquery.jobs.create}. And reference should follow the pattern; PROJECT_ID:DATASET.TABLE

Comment: thanks for the response @chaiyachaiya - Use case added.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you take a look at this [document](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/copying-datasets) where is explained how to copy datasets across projects, as is mentioned there:

"You can copy a dataset within a region or from one region to another, without extracting, moving, and reloading data into BigQuery. You can copy the dataset one time or on a customized recurring schedule."

Just consider have the proper permissions for this action:

- The bigquery.transfers.update permission to create the copy transfer.
- The bigquery.tables.list permission on the source dataset.

Also, you can find different examples of how execute this task, for example using [bq](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/copying-datasets#bq) commands:

```
bq mk --transfer_config --project_id=PROJECT_ID --data_source=DATA_SOURCE --target_dataset=DATASET --display_name=NAME --params='PARAMETERS'
```

Answer (score 0):

It was easier than I thought.
Just mess a little with the auth.
For e.g In Proj_A , I would do either of the following:

```
bigquery.Client(project='Proj_B', credentials=credsobject_of_Proj_B)

or
# Don't pass the credentials and let it default to inferred from the environment
os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = Key_File_Proj_B
bigquery.Client(project='Proj_B')
```

In this way BigQuery doesn't search for the dataset in the current project but in the project that is passed as param. Do remember to give the service account BigQuery jobs create and editor access in Proj_B to allow it to write the data.

Comment: Good for you if it works but I keep thinking that it's kind of weird. You don't need to create a keyfile from project B so your process in project A will act as if it belongs to project B and hence looks for tables in project B (by default). My piece of advice. Keep the default identity of your cloud function and declare the associated service account in the IAM of project B with the needed rights. In your initial problem you may also have misspell the table ref that needs the project ID: TableReference.from_string('my-project.mydataset.mytable').

Comment: Also, you should add an intermediary step in your flow, i.e put the raw data at rest in a datalake. What if you need to replay the data? It may have disapeared from the source URI when you decide to.  GCS is a good location to benefits from low storage price and high transfer performance to BigQuery.  Transfer can be done automatically by attaching a cloud function to the file creation event in GCS.